# Objective-C strange error SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

I am learning Objecive-C and try to removeObject method in loop. 
It is not work correctly. I recive "Thread 1: Program received signal:"SIGABRT"." on that line.
What is wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *bookListMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"TitleM 2", @"TitleM 4", @"TitleM 5", nil];
[bookListMutable addObject:@"TitleM 3 added"];
[bookListMutable insertObject:@"TitleM 1 inserted" atIndex:0];

long countMutable;
countMutable = bookListMutable.count;


for(int y = 0; y < countMutable; y++){
    [bookListMutable removeObject:[bookListMutable objectAtIndex:y]];
}
```

P.S. xCode 4.1

Comment: 1) Time to update, there's an Xcode 4.3. 2) SIGABRT is usually an exception. Did you check the console?

Comment: Which line is that? Also, why aren't you using `removeObjectAtIndex:`, or for that matter `removeAllObjects`?!

Comment: I tried to do exercise from this book http://www.amazon.com/Objective-C-Absolute-Beginners-iPhone-Programming/dp/1430228326/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1329685777&sr=8-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not remove items in that order. Let's say the array has 4 items `{0, 1, 2, 3}` and simulate the execution of the program:

1. First iteration with `y = 0`: removing item at index `0` from `{0, 1, 2, 3}` gives `{1, 2, 3}`.
2. Second iteration with `y = 1`: removing item at index `1` from `{1, 2, 3}` gives `{1, 3}`
3. Third iteration with `y = 2`: removing item at index `2` from `{1, 3}` gives. Oops, there is no item at index 2 => Exception.

So you should iterate backwards like this:

```
for(int y = countMutable-1; y >= 0; y--) {
    [bookListMutable removeAtIndex:y]];
}
```

or use the build in method:

```
[bookListMutable removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're removing items in the wrong order. Once you remove the item at index 0, all indexes are decremented by one. So you might do this:

```
for(int y = countMutable-1; y >= 0; y--) {
    [bookListMutable removeObject:[bookListMutable objectAtIndex:y]];
}
```

or this:

```
for(int y = 0; y < countMutable; y++) {
    [bookListMutable removeObject:[bookListMutable objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

(I'm leaving this as a minor modification to your code, but would like to note that there are better ways to do things like this, e.g. using `removeObjectAtIndex:`. See the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

I see quite a few things that could be wrong with your code, but the thing that looks worst: you're deleting objects in the array starting at index 0, going up to the count. This will mean that i=0,1,2,3, while the array continues to shift elements back to position 0. This will definitely throw an exception, and only half the array can be wiped this way.

Alternative: use the method that clears the array (`[bookListMutable removeAllObjects]`), or iterate down from the count to 0.